# How to set base64 data image texture on a-sky in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

Hi i'm trying to set a base64 image to  by doing this
`document.querySelector('a-sky').setAttribute('src',base64Data);`
but this doesn't work and causes aframe to create a lot of warnings in the console

`core:schema:warn Unknown property`3200`for component/system`material``

This used to work when i was using the `0.3.2` version of Aframe, and it is now breaking on the version `0.4.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the base64 data in `url()` so it gets parsed cleanly.

`document.querySelector('a-sky').setAttribute('src', 'url(' + base64Data + ')');`

We recommend using the `url()` wrapper whenever using base64 data or non-trivial URLs.

Comment: I am doing same, loading base64Data into a-sky, but not load the image, can you please help me to show more code?

Comment: My code: this.swivelFitService.getImage(this.imageURL).subscribe( base64Data => { console.log('On getImage() subscribe:' +base64Data); document.querySelector('a-sky').setAttribute('src', 'url(' + base64Data + ')'); });